# web api with multiple complex parameters

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, mailmessage

I am trying to create an email service web api with multiple attachments. Need to have only one parameter for web api. But, right now I have 2 complex parameters, which web api doesn't accept. Please suggest how do I implement multiple attachments and use only one complex parameter for web api.

```
[HttpPost]          
[ActionName("sendemail")]
public IHttpActionResult processEmail(EmailModel emailModel, 
List<HttpPostedFileBase> attachments)
{
 ........
}
```

EmailModel

```
 public class EmailModel
    {  
        public string ToAddress { get; set; }
        public string FromAddress { get; set; }       
        public string Body { get; set; }

    }
```

And, in Email Controller I use the list to attach the attachments to MailMessage object.

```
 foreach (HttpPostedFileBase attachment in attachments)
   {                
            if (attachment != null)
            {
                    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(attachment.FileName);                   

                    //create linked resource for embedding image
                    LinkedResource pic = new LinkedResource(attachment.InputStream, "image/jpg");                    

                    //add linked resource to appropriate view  
                    htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(pic);
             }

     }

      //add view
      msg.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to accept your email model as your parameter, and grab the uploaded files in the HttpContext.Request.Files to loop over. That's assuming you are posting with multipart/form-data

Comment: Ok, so in test MVC application, with view and the controller having all the mailmessage logic, the above works. But, in a Web API application, where the email controller's main logic resides, I am stuck at how to call the web api with email model parameter from a client app.

Comment: You will need to use HttpContext.Request.Form to get the emailmodel and include those with your form. Does that help?

Comment: As a follow up - you can do something like this to deserialize your EmailModel if you use Json.NET:
`var emailModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EmailModel>(Request.Form["emailModel"]);`

Assuming your client is using something like JSON.stringify to send your EmailModel as a JSON object.

Hope that helps